# Select List of Column Names / Aliases from Custom Sub-Query

Tags: oracle, list, format, subquery, alias

In Oracle, is there a way to select all the columns that are returned from a custom query with aliases? As an example, let's say we have a query as the following:

```
    SELECT FIRST_NAME AS COL1, LAST_NAME AS COL2, ADDRESS AS COL3
    FROM PEOPLE
```

I would like to know if an encapsulating query can be made that would return:

```
    COL1
    COL2
    COL3
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (your subquery)` will do that.

Comment: I believe that would return something like:

def Col1      Col2      Col3
end
John      Smith     123 ABC st.
Jane      Doe       987 XYZ Rd.

Comment: You mean you just want the aliased column names from the query, not the actual results?

Comment: That is correct; I just want the aliases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it in PL/SQL.  Don't know if it is possible with straight oracle SQL only.  You could always encapulate it in some kind of function if needed.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE RefCursor_Type IS REF CURSOR;

   D_RefCur             RefCursor_Type;
   D_DescriptionTable   DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2;
   D_ColumnCount        INTEGER;
   D_CursorHandle       INTEGER;
BEGIN
   OPEN D_RefCur
   FOR 'SELECT FIRST_NAME AS COL1, LAST_NAME AS COL2, ADDRESS AS COL3 FROM PEOPLE';

   D_CursorHandle := DBMS_SQL.to_cursor_number (D_RefCur);

   DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2 (D_CursorHandle,
                               D_ColumnCount,
                               D_DescriptionTable);


   FOR idx IN 1 .. D_ColumnCount
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (D_DescriptionTable (idx).col_name);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: No problem.  Its funny because I just had to use the DBMS_SQL package to get query column data for a project.  Good timing!