# extracting titles from sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

is there a simple way of getting the column titles from a given sql query.

So from the following:

```
select name, dob, trunc((sysdate-dob)/365.25) age, address "Persons address" from persons
```

one would get:

```
NAME
DOB
AGE
Persons address
```

Comment: Why u need only the titles without the data?

Comment: do you use your sql in a certain application, like java or other programming framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select List of Column Names / Aliases from Custom Sub-Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198923/select-list-of-column-names-aliases-from-custom-sub-query)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select only column name from an sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908863/select-only-column-name-from-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

The alias name cannot be displayed directly unless it is saved in database but we can create a table form the select statement like below

```
create table persons_temp as
select name, dob, trunc((sysdate-dob)/365.25) age, address "Persons address" from persons
```

then we can query the data dictionary table user_tab_columns like

```
   select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'PERSONS_TEMP'
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Programs such as TOAD put the column titles at the top of their output grids when you run a query and presumably they don't save anything to the database before doing this.

Comment: @TonyWolff yes probably they are just alias name, hence the display of name can be done only by this way.

Answer (score 0):

TOAD and other tools and environments can display column titles, because column information can be retrieved after *parsing* the statement, which is done when you execute it.

Depending on your environment, it is possible you can write code to call parse of your query and then the parsed statement will be an object with a collection of column objects that have name and datatype and length as attributes. That is possible in many programming languages that support preparing and executing SQL statements.

In PL/SQL you can also parse a statement and retrieve column information using package DBMS_SQL. Take a look in the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68199 (scroll down to example 8.)

A simplified adaptation of example 8 just giving column names you need:

```
declare
   c           number;
   col_cnt     integer;
   rec_tab     dbms_sql.desc_tab;
begin
   c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

   dbms_sql.parse(c, q'[SELECT 'a' col1, 3 "Col2" FROM dual]', dbms_sql.native);

   dbms_sql.describe_columns(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);

   for j in 1..col_cnt loop
      dbms_output.put_line(rec_tab(j).col_name);
   end loop;

   dbms_sql.close_cursor(c);
end;
/
```

This will output (if you have dbms_output turned on, of course) the following:

```
COL1
Col2
```

If you see the example 8 in the documentation you can see that other column information is also available, like datatype, length, precision and such.